# OutOfMemory although Heap Size is less than 6MB

Tags: android, heap-memory

In my Android developer console, I see some crashes with

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=5795KB, Allocated=3859KB)
```

Especially the small Heap Size (less than 6MB) surprises me.

How do I have to interpret this Heap Size? Is this the size of the heap prior to the OOM call? Can I assume that the max heap is at least 16MB? If so, does this mean that I tried to allocate a block of at least 10MB (16MB - 6MB) ?

Comment: I quick look tell me that you are trying to allocate something bigger than 5795KB - 3859KB and the heap size is 6MB

Comment: @mathk I always thought that an Android application had at least 16MB heap available.  Isn't this true?

Comment: the image dimensoion (width and heigth)?

Comment: The OOM occurs when loading data @ application startup (no images). I'm mainly wondering how I should interpret the Heap Size. I guess this is the current size of the heap, right? This means that there should be at least 10MB available prior to the call triggering the OOM, right?

Comment: Usually such an error is accompanied by other messages from the VM indicating how much it was trying to allocate. Are you not getting any other messages? Also, this heap is only the VM heap, it doesn't include memory which has been allocated on the native heap. Especially bitmaps are all allocated in the native heap.

Comment: Indeed, in Logcat, I do remember seeing additional information when running into an OOM (long time ago, not related to this OOM).  However, these reports come from the Android developer console and don't contain this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to check the memory status:

```
ActivityManager actMgr = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ActivityManager.MemoryInfo minfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
actMgr.getMemoryInfo(minfo);
if(minfo.lowMemory) { //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet.  However, I'm mainly trying to understand why I'm running into the OOM, given that the used heap is about 6MB and there should be (afaik) at least 16MB available.